# How to update react component state based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-state-management

How can I force a react component to update state whenever props change?

I have been using the method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({key:nextProps}); 
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

The console shows me that nextProps is the defined value, but this.state.key remains undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you are deriving state from props, it might be a better idea to do those calculations in `render` instead of updating state.

Comment: I'm working on an app with 2 main components. The first sends an onlick ajax request, then passes that information to the second component via props. I need the second component to update when the props change.

Comment: @JSX Component updates itself when props changes. For this purpose you do not need to add it in state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console log this.state shows undefined because setState is asynchronous. Hence when you perform setState it does not update state immediately and that's why console log doesn't show updated state.

You should do as follows:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({key:nextProps}, () => {
        console.log(this.state);
    }); 
 }
```

Here when setState will take place the callback defined as a second parameter gets called and then we have updated state.

Comment: Just an FYI componentWillReceiveProps was recommended to now be unsafe not too long ago: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle